# Can I save nested Layers in a long format table?

Tags: qgis, table, qfield, relates

I want to create a QGIS project for sampling crustaceans in rivers using Qfield. I want to collect environmental data as well as the abundance of each species found in different microhabitats.
So far i have tried to link Layers with parent child relations. However i´m afraid that the data analysis will be messy because i´d have to link 4 tables by IDs. Also i´m not sure if it would even work like this in Qfield. Here is an image of editing the nested layers:
[image]

I can only export each layer as a seperate table.
Instead i wish to save my data in one table using long format like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation, and can confirm that parent-child forms work in QField (in my case it was one parent and one child, though...).

In case it doesn't work with so many forms linked to each other, I can recommend splitting this into several layers, especially for the first form, where you have only one variable.

Also, merging by IDs works perfectly in R, so I can recommend using it for data processing after the collection!

Comment: Thank you, i followed your advice and split it into several layers. It is a bit more work in the field, but i think it is saver that way